# How to write to file in relative path?

Tags: java, maven

```
/jde/src/main/resources/files
```

"jde" is my project name. Under the "files" directory, I have an "input.txt" file. I can read this file with relative path:

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("files/input.txt");
    if (is == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(" File not found");
    }
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

However, I am not able to write to the file: "files/output.txt". I was trying to do something like the following:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(outputFileName);
```

URL is null, in this way. So how to write to relative path file in a standard Maven Java Project?

Comment: Classpath resources are not meant to be writable. Deploy the file somewhere you have write access and use a `FileWriter` or other NIO/IO mechanism to write to it.

Comment: Do you mean I have to use "absolute path" anyway?

Comment: What's wrong with `new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` ?